# Alphabet to integers

Tags: python, arrays, integer, alphabet

I'm trying to create a programm in which a user inputs a string e.g 'roller' and the program converts the alphabet to numbers such as `a=1, b=2, c=3` etc, and the calculate the sum of these values. But, if the program finds two same letters in a row then it doubles the sum. So far I have done this:

```
input = raw_input('Write Text: ')
input = input.lower()
output = []
sum=0
for character in input:
    number = ord(character) - 96
    sum=sum+number
    output.append(number)
print sum
```

which calculates the sum of the characters and also appends the converted characters to a new array. So can anyone help me to double the sum if two letters appear in a row?

Comment: Can you give some example inputs and outputs for input like `abbba`, `aabaa` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the previous character and compare it to the current character.  If they're the same, double the value.

```
word = 'hello'
out = []
c_prev = None

for c in word:
    value = ord(c) - ord('a')

    if c == c_prev:  # double if repeated character
        value = value * 2

    out.append(value)
    c_prev = c  # store for next comparison

print(sum(out))
```